# What is the easiest way to draw graphics on Linux framebuffer?

Tags: linux, embedded, gui, framebuffer

I have some embedded Linux ARM chip with LCD display on frame-buffer. I connect to chip with serial console. I can access frame-buffer directly with low-level commands.

However I need to draw some figures or even sprites. I am searching something. Can for example SDL run on frame-buffer without X, or there is similar graphical libraries?

High performance video like speed is not needed, because probably animation will not be used, but GUI should be at least usable.

Ncurses was useful for text interface, but I need some graphical interface.

Comment: I know that GTK supports DirectFB (http://www.directfb.org/) as one of its backends, but never used it: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/gtk-directfb.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DirectFB](https://web.archive.org/web/20161104003307/http://www.directfb.net/) might be what you are looking for. If you needed higher level API, [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) should be able to use it as its backend.

Comment: Something real fishy is on the DirectFB site now, was just reading and very confused because important link/info is mentioned they're all to porno sites?! I think they got hacked..

Comment: Probably went out of business, I've replaced the link with archived version.